# QtStyleSheet not being applied to the title header of the application

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

code:

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    File = open("src\main\Style Sheets\Combinear.qss", 'r')

    with File:
        qss = File.read()
        self.setStyleSheet(qss)
```

Also the Style Sheet is being applied to a QMainWindow object.

picture:

[image: window]

Comment: Please try to be more clear with your questions, as right now it's not only unclear what you're asking, but the code you're providing is completely useless. What is the content of the stylesheet? And what do you mean by "title header"? Also, please review the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: In the image everything has the style applied to it but the very top of the application and I am confused on why that is.

Comment: What is "the very top"? The title bar? The menubar? The title bar depends on the OS, stylesheets can do *nothing* with that. If you're referring to the menubar, then, as already requested, we must know the contents of the stylesheet.

Comment: Did you read all lines or just 1 line and ignored the rest? Sorry Im rusty with Python, but but does read() return all or just 1? Did u encode/decode bytes to that style can be applied?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.